# sge: How to set hard limits of node?

Tags: cluster, gridengine, distributed-computing

The guy who administrates our cluster died suddenly and recently, so now we have to operate it ourselves until a new guy comes in. We want to change the hard runtime limit of a node on our cluster. For some reason, all the nodes in a queue has the desired hard runtime limit, but one of them does not.

How can I set h_rt=x for a given x?

Comment: welcome, and sorry to hear. However: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Please show relevant server configuration & settings, versions, log and/or error messages. In general: it is almost impossible to add too much information to a question, but there is definitely too little now. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using linux clustering, so this answer is based off of that assumption:

**You need to modify the limits.conf file in /etc/security/**

You will need to be root or be able to sudo in order to save your changes.
Once you have the file opened with your editor you should see four columns: Domain, Type, Item, Value.

You are looking to change the Value for one or more of the Hard type objects.